# spark-submit on ibm bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

i've just registrated a free instance of "Analitycs for Apache Spark" and followed this [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/04/20/launch-a-spark-job-using-spark-submit/#status) to use spark submit ibm ad hoc designed script to run an app from my local machine on bluemix cloud cluster. The issue is the following: i've made everithing that was described in the tutorial and lunched this script

```
./spark-submit.sh --vcap ./vcap.json --deploy-mode cluster --master
 https://spark.eu-gb.bluemix.net --files /home/vito/vinorosso2.csv
 --conf spark.service.spark_version=2.2.0 
/home/vito/workspace_2/sbt-esempi/target/scala-2.11/isolationF3.jar 
--class  progettoSisDis.MasterNode
```

everything proceed fine (dataset vinorosso2.csv and my fatJar are correctly uploaded) until the terminal sais :" submission complete" at this point when i go to the log file created by the script there was this error message :

> Submit job result: Invalid plan and spark version combination in HTTP request (ibm.SparkService.PayGoPersonal, 2.0.0)
>
> Submission ID:
> ERROR: Problem submitting job. Exit

So, it wasn't enough to register a free instance of Analitycs for apache spark to submit a spark job? Hope someone can help. By the way, if it helps, on my local machine i'm using spark with intellij idea (scala). Byyye

Answer (score 0):

From https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic2.html#using_spark-submit you need to be using Spark version 1.6.x or 2.0.x. Your submit job is set to version 2.2.0.  Try submitting using `spark.service.spark_version=2.0.0` (assuming your code will work with this version of Spark).

Comment: Hi shawdm, i already tried this one without success. it reports the same error messag but instead of (ibm.SparkService.PayGoPersonal, 2.2.0) i receive (ibm.SparkService.PayGoPersonal, 2.0.0).Any other ideas?